# Best analysis for count data as response variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, count-data

I want to know what is the best way to analyze a data set where my response variable is count data and my explanatory variables are continuous variables. All my variables are not normally distributed. Are GLMs a good option?

Answer (score 10):

They are. You may want to look at *Poisson regression* (in R: `glm(..., family=poisson, ...)`) or, if you have overdispersion, *Negbin regression* or, if you have "too many" zeros, *ZIP regression* (Zero-Inflated Poisson).

Whether the *predictors* are normally distributed does not matter. (Except for analyses of influential data points.) What you probably have in mind is whether *residuals* are normally distributed. This is an important assumption in Ordinary Least Squares - more specifically: for inference in OLS. However, your data are counts, so residuals will not be normal and you are not thinking about OLS, anyway.

Comment: it might be good to clarify your second paragraph so that it is clear it applies only to the post's idea about normality of variables.

Comment: @PeterFlom: good point, thanks! I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-normal GLM, the distribution of residuals do not matter, I have never heard that a Poisson GLM for example has to have normal errors.  I think that examining overdispersion and general model fit are better cues to which model to use.  Negative binomial can be implemented in glm.nb() in the R MASS library, and ZIP can be done using the zeroinfl() function in the pscl library in R

Comment: *"For a non-normal GLM, the distribution of residuals do not matter"* - this statement is false, the distribution of residuals and thus the error structure is strictly defined by the GLM family: poisson, binomial, ...

Comment: But it is not strictly normal